# R Regex with Stringr: character(0) Error

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm trying to recreate an old project. However, I'm guessing something changed in the stringr package because my code no longer works. Minimum working example (MWE):

```
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.lq.com/en/findandbook.html"
page <- GET(url)
s <- content(page, as="text")
push <- unlist(str_match_all(s, "hotelList.push?.+?}")) # stopped working
```

Error message:

```
> push <- unlist(str_match_all(s, "hotelList.push?.+?}")) # stopped working
Error in stri_match_all_regex(string, pattern, cg_missing = "", omit_no_match = TRUE,  : 
Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

My fix:

```
> push <- unlist(str_match_all(s, "hotelList.push?.+?\\}")) # stopped working
> push
character(0)
```

The string, `s`, has lines of text. I am trying to find the lines that look like:

```
"hotelList.push({title: \"La Quinta Inn & Suites Phoenix I-10 West\", innNumber: \"0853\", latitude:})"
```

and grab everything between the curly braces. I suck at regular expressions, so after Googling I found the following two suggestions that also did not work.

```
str_match_all(s, "/{(.*?)}/")
str_match_all(s, "/{([^}]*)}/")
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the forward slash and escape the curly braces.

```
str_match_all(s, "\\{([^}]*)\\}")
```

or

```
str_match_all(s, "\\{\\K[^}]*(?=\\})")
```

Comment: Very helpful. How do I grab the lines that have the pattern: `hotelList.push({......})` though?

Comment: use this `"hotelList\\.push\\(\\{.*?\\}\\)"`

Comment: That didn't work, but this did: `str_match_all(s, "hotelList\\.push\\(\\{([^}]*)\\}"))`. Thank you very much @avinish-raj

Comment: @user2205916 because it contain line breaks in-between, try `"(?s)hotelList\\.push\\(\\{.*?\\}\\)"`

Comment: "hotelList.push({title: \"La Quinta Inn & Suites Phoenix I-10 West\", innNumber: \"0853\", latitude:}" is returned but how do get just: "{title: \"La Quinta Inn & Suites Phoenix I-10 West\", innNumber: \"0853\", latitude:}"?